# relation "<a new model>" does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I have a Django project consist of several apps. I've added a new model on my `settings` app:

```py
class DataFrameAdjustment(models.Model):
    bunch_size = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    timeout = models.CharField(
        max_length=3, choices=Strings.TIMEOUT,
        default="3", blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.bunch_size} - {self.timeout}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Data Frame Adjustment'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Data Frame Adjustments'
```

At the moment, I'm dealing with the following error:

```py
from settings.models import DataFrameAdjustment

df = DataFrameAdjustment.objects.all()
print(df)  # For test.
```

Out:

```
Out[11]: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UndefinedTable                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute(self, sql, params, *ignored_wrapper_args)
     83             else:
---> 84                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
     85 

UndefinedTable: relation "settings_dataframeadjustment" does not exist
LINE 1: ...e", "settings_dataframeadjustment"."timeout" FROM "settings_...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    700                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    701                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 702             printer.pretty(obj)
    703             printer.flush()
    704             return stream.getvalue()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py in pretty(self, obj)
    403                         if cls is not object \
    404                                 and callable(cls.__dict__.get('__repr__')):
--> 405                             return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    406 
    407             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py in _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    693     """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
    694     # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
--> 695     output = repr(obj)
    696     lines = output.splitlines()
    697     with p.group():

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __repr__(self)
    248 
    249     def __repr__(self):
--> 250         data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
    251         if len(data) > REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE:
    252             data[-1] = "...(remaining elements truncated)..."

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __iter__(self)
    272                - Responsible for turning the rows into model objects.
    273         """
--> 274         self._fetch_all()
    275         return iter(self._result_cache)
    276 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in _fetch_all(self)
   1240     def _fetch_all(self):
   1241         if self._result_cache is None:
-> 1242             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
   1243         if self._prefetch_related_lookups and not self._prefetch_done:
   1244             self._prefetch_related_objects()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __iter__(self)
     53         # Execute the query. This will also fill compiler.select, klass_info,
     54         # and annotations.
---> 55         results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
     56         select, klass_info, annotation_col_map = (compiler.select, compiler.klass_info,
     57                                                   compiler.annotation_col_map)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in execute_sql(self, result_type, chunked_fetch, chunk_size)
   1095             cursor = self.connection.cursor()
   1096         try:
-> 1097             cursor.execute(sql, params)
   1098         except Exception:
   1099             # Might fail for server-side cursors (e.g. connection closed)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/raven/contrib/django/client.py in execute(self, sql, params)
    125         start = time.time()
    126         try:
--> 127             return real_execute(self, sql, params)
    128         finally:
    129             record_sql(self.db.vendor, getattr(self.db, 'alias', None),

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute(self, sql, params)
     65 
     66     def execute(self, sql, params=None):
---> 67         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
     68 
     69     def executemany(self, sql, param_list):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute_with_wrappers(self, sql, params, many, executor)
     74         for wrapper in reversed(self.db.execute_wrappers):
     75             executor = functools.partial(wrapper, executor)
---> 76         return executor(sql, params, many, context)
     77 
     78     def _execute(self, sql, params, *ignored_wrapper_args):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute(self, sql, params, *ignored_wrapper_args)
     82                 return self.cursor.execute(sql)
     83             else:
---> 84                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
     85 
     86     def _executemany(self, sql, param_list, *ignored_wrapper_args):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py in __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
     87                 if dj_exc_type not in (DataError, IntegrityError):
     88                     self.wrapper.errors_occurred = True
---> 89                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
     90 
     91     def __call__(self, func):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute(self, sql, params, *ignored_wrapper_args)
     82                 return self.cursor.execute(sql)
     83             else:
---> 84                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
     85 
     86     def _executemany(self, sql, param_list, *ignored_wrapper_args):

ProgrammingError: relation "settings_dataframeadjustment" does not exist
LINE 1: ...e", "settings_dataframeadjustment"."timeout" FROM "settings_...
                                                             ^
```

## What avenues should I pursue to fix this problem?

---

Here's what I've done so far:

```
python manage.py makemigrations settings
python manage.py migrate settings
```

Out [**UPDATE**]:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: settings
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

However, the problem still remains.

I've seen similar questions on StackOverflow, though they didn't help me.

---

[**UPDATE2**]:

```
python manage.py showmigrations


admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
 [X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
 [X] 0010_alter_group_name_max_length
 [X] 0011_update_proxy_permissions
backup_restore_app
 [X] 0001_initial
battery_monitoring
 [X] 0001_initial
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
datapipeline
 [X] 0001_initial
ivms_app
 [X] 0001_initial
map_app
 [X] 0001_initial
menu
 [X] 0001_initial
modbus_app
 [X] 0001_initial
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
settings
 [X] 0001_initial
siemens_s7
 [X] 0001_initial
snmp_app
 [X] 0001_initial
```

---

[**UPDATE4**]:

```
python manage.py migrate settings zero

Operations to perform:
  Unapply all migrations: settings
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

---

[**UPDATE5**]:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations

No changes detected

$ python manage.py migrate

Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, backup_restore_app, battery_monitoring, contenttypes, datapipeline, ivms_app, map_app, menu, modbus_app, sessions, settings, siemens_s7, snmp_app
Running migrations:
  Applying settings.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "settings_legendhelppage" already exists
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

- *DataBase: postgresql*
- *Django version 2.2.10*
- *Python version 3.6.8*

Comment: Usually, the import is `from <someapp>.models import <SomeModel>`. Not `from settings.models ...`.

Comment: You could look inside the database itself; it's likely your table is named differently, and if I'm correct in my previous comment, more like `someapp_dataframeadjustment`.

Comment: @BearBrown I'm updating my question with `migrate setting` traceback

Comment: @BearBrown No, how could I do it?

Comment: @00 `settings` is my app name

Comment: That seems to be a poorly chosen app name, since `settings.py` is the module where all the settings are stored. Namespacing may keep things apart, but it certainly would make things harder to comprehend.

Comment: @BearBrown I updated it by `[UPDATE2]` tag.

Comment: @BearBrown I've deleted the `settings/migrations` folder before

Comment: and after you run `makemigrations` and `migrate` you get the same output as before?

Comment: @BearBrown I think yes. Ok I'll try it. But do you mean `python manage.py migrate zero`?

Comment: sorry `python manage.py migrate settings zero`

Comment: @BearBrown I've done it as UPDATE3

Comment: you need to delete the record about migration for the settings application, try to execute in the database `DELETE FROM django_migrations WHERE app='settings'` and then run migration

Comment: @BearBrown I executed the mentioned query. Afterward, I ran `python manage.py migrate settings zero` without any problem. But the problem still remains

Comment: you need to start your migration process now, make migration and try to apply it.

Comment: @BearBrown Unfortunately, another problem has been occurred (UPDATE5).

Comment: it is mean that the table `settings_legendhelppage` exists and you need drop it (make backup version if you need to save data)

Comment: @BearBrown I had to drop all tables in the `settings` app using `psql` by this sort of commands: `DROP TABLE desired-tables CASCADE`. Eventually, the problem has been fixed. Thank you very much for your much time effort.

Comment: glad to help you